# JavaScript pre-loader with button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a 'pre-page' for my game in JavaScript, and have created a class which sits in front of my main content. I've given my button a  'onclick' function called fadeOut() for my JavaScript, however it doesn't work.

```
<div id="loader1" class="loader">
  <img src="assets/zelda-quest-white.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate nisi ac eros auctor, sed eleifend diam dignissim. Maecenas vel viverra est, vitae volutpat enim. Pellentesque posuere fermentum volutpat. Duis laoreet porttitor dapibus. Phasellus viverra leo augu.</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="fadeOut()">Fade Out</button>
</div>
```

I've created a class called .loader and assigned an opacity transition of 2s.

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

And in JavaScript

```
  function fadeOut() {
    const square = document.querySelector('#loader1')
    square.style.opacity = '0'
  }
```

This is the page loader.
[image]

When the page loads, I want that content to disappear so my content will show.
[image]

Comment: add `opacity:1;` to css

Comment: this is working fine for me. do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: if you set an `opacity` to `0` nothing will be visible anyway what are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

@Pain, I get an error which says fadeOut() is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

I tried the opacity: 1, and that didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function works. By running your code, I found the color of the words are the same as the background, which is the reason why only a button appears after loading the page.

I add `color: white;` in css and `<div>Main Content</div>` in the end of HTML. The text appears after clicking the button.

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader1" class="loader">
  <img src="assets/zelda-quest-white.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate nisi ac eros auctor, sed eleifend diam dignissim. Maecenas vel viverra est, vitae volutpat enim. Pellentesque posuere fermentum volutpat. Duis laoreet porttitor dapibus. Phasellus viverra leo augu.</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="fadeOut()">Fade Out</button>
</div>

<div>Main Content</div>

<script>
    function fadeOut() {
      const square = document.querySelector('#loader1')
      square.style.opacity = '0'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alan. I tired using your code snippets, however it didn't work. As above, I get a condole log error saying that fadeOut() is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

Comment: I think the javascript code may not be included in your html code. I modified the snippet by adding script tag in html. You can try that again.

Comment: Thanks Alan, this is working now. By any chance, do you know how I could get this working inside my JavaScript document, instead of inside of my HTML page, or can it only work inside my page?

Comment: You can add a script tag with path of your js file. For example, if your js file is called prePage.js and is in the same folder as html file, you can use <script src="prePage.js"></script>